# JavaCC match token group

Tags: javacc

I ended up writing a parser for a small subset of SQL.
The grammar has a lot of regular tokens (SELECT, CREATE, ...) and a few more general (e.g. S_GEN_IDENTIFIER matches `[A-Z_.\d]|\"(~[\n, \r, \"])*\")`.

The problem is, "SELECT col AS type ..." doesn't get parsed since instead of `<S_GEN_IDENTIFIER>` "type" column alias is matched as `<T_TYPE>`.

I had an idea to replace  token with a rule with the same name and check is the token of interest lies within some token range (something like `[<T_AS> - <T_KEEP_DUPLICATES>]`. Unfortunately it turned out that the syntax for tokens and rules differs so I can't do it.
I could just copy-paste all tokens inside the new rule but I don't want to do it for obvious reasons.

Is there any way to check if token lies within the range of predefined tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could treat "type" as an unreserved keyword. Then you can follow the advice of question 4.19 of the FAQ
  http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc4.19

Comment: Thank you for the link. Indeed most of the common SQL keywords are reserved. But I use Oracle which has many unreserved keywords and apparently in my case copy-paste is unavoidable.